# Using included mode that doesn't have a MIME in CodeMirror.overlayPerser()

Tags: javascript, codemirror

`getMode` works with modes that have MIME like `text/plain` or `text/html`. How can I make it work with `jinja2`? This doesn't work:

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("htmljinja", function(config, parserConfig) {
    return CodeMirror.overlayParser(CodeMirror.getMode(config, parserConfig.backdrop || "text/html"), CodeMirror.getMode(config, "jinja2"));
});
```

`"text/jinja2"` doesn't work either. How can I do this without coping the whole `mode/jinja2.js` in my file?

Comment: That actually works just fine for me. Did you include all the needed files? (mode/xml/xml.js, mode/jinja2/jinja2.js, addon/mode/overlay.js)

Comment: My bad! I didn't include overlay.js! :|